# Detect ERR_NETWROK_CHANGED (Chrome) via JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have an iframe on the website and when people do stuff inside it, they sometimes (appears to be Chrome users only) experience a ERR_NETWROK_CHANGED error. In this case they lose all the stuff they worked on and I understand this is frustrating for them. Is there a way to detect this ERR_NETWROK_CHANGED error (or any other similar errors for that matter) via JS?
Something that comes to mind is `window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { /* do stuff */ });` - in case it's offline, we can assume this happened. I'm also thinking this is a bit error-prone, but I'm not quite sure what else to do.
Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Why setting an interval? Using a listener on `offline`/`online` should be enough, although, it seems every navigator do not implement it the same way, so I guess you'll have to be careful.

Comment: @sjahan - thanks you're right, a bit tired and not thinking clearly... I modified the question now.